# Enable Button with on change of Select

Tags: javascript, button, onchange

I need help calling my function, it is not recognizing it and i cannot see why? Any answers to why this is not working...thanks
    
    
    Broken

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$('select').change(function() {
alert("hi");
    var op =$(this).val();
    if(op !='') {                 
    $('input[name="processor_details"]').prop('disabled',false);
} else {
    $('input[name="processor_details"]').prop('disabled', true);
}   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<strong>Processor:</strong>
 <select class="custom-pc" name="processor" id="processor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>                
    </select>
 <input name="processor_details" type="button" value="Details" disabled="true" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script not see the `select` because it's below script itself. You can put your script below select or wrap it with `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/cchdW/

It is working on Chrome and Firefox on Mac. Are you sure you are calling JQuery? You did not paste the full HTML code. I think you are missing JQuery. This code will not work without JQuery.

Also, you have to wrap it `$(window).load(function(){}` in like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
  $('select').change(function() {
    alert("hi");
    var op =$(this).val();
    if(op !='') {                 
      $('input[name="processor_details"]').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
      $('input[name="processor_details"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }   
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Im using the following to call it; is this incorrect?   
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: You have to wrap it $(window).load(function(){}, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Ken you should probably put the protocol in that `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>; ` otherwise you'll be loading `http://yoursite.com/code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` also, if this is going live what happens when jquery updates and deprecates or removes methods your code uses? better to load a specific version that your code is known to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fun()
{
    if(document.getElementById("processor").value!="")
        document.getElementById("button").disabled=false;
    else
    document.getElementById("button").disabled=true;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<strong>Processor:</strong>
 <select class="custom-pc" name="processor" id="processor" onChange="fun()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>                
    </select>
 <input name="processor_details" type="button" value="Details" id="button" disabled="true" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```